# Is there a list of cards for Machi Koro 2?

Tags: machi-koro

I am thinking about acquiring Machi Koro 2.

My problem is that in my country I can only get the original, Machi Koro 2 has not been officially released here, so I would have to import it.

I have heard that the second version is better, but it would be more expensive for me to buy it.

I did some research and apparently, there is not a big difference between the cards on the original MK with expansions and MK2 aside from the landmark cards. I was wondering if someone has a full list of cards of Machi Koro 2, so I can compare the two and see if with some paste-ups I can use the cards from the original Machi Koro, with expansions, to play Machi Koro 2?

Comment: I have both games and I don't think you can easily change your Machi Koro 1 into 2.  I would look a tabletop simulator or go to a local gaming store to try out the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've included a list of the cards and quantity of each. All a total of 106 cards. You can [download the rulebook from their page](https://pandasaurusgames.com/products/machi-koro-2).

| cards | qty |
| --- | --- |
| Sushi Bar, Wheat Field, Vineyard, Bakery, Cafe, Flower Garden, Convenience Store, Forest, Corn Field, Hamburger Stand, Family Restaurant, Apple Orchard, Mine | 5 |
| Flower Shop, Business Center, Stadium, Furniture Factory, Shopping District, Winery, Food Warehouse | 3 |
| Landmarks: Airport, Amusement Park, Charterhouse, Exhibit Hall, Farmers Market, Forge, French Restaurant, Launch Pad, Loan Office, Moving Company, Museum, Observatory, Park, Publisher, Radio Tower, Soda Bottling Plant, Shopping Mall, Tech Startup, Temple, TV Station | 1 |